# Medical imaging with tcia data

Tags: python, image, medical, medical-imaging, nifti

I'm trying to build CNN network for MRI data from tcia dataset.

However, transferring DICOM format to nifti format is not working after using dicom2nifti.

The coding did worked, but did not gave a file.

Is this is because of the data format from tcia dataset that ends with .tcia?

Thanks a lot. Below is the data format and the code I used for dicom2n[image]

[[image: 1]

Comment: The links to the tcia files are not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the .tcia file extension stands for "The Cancer Imaging Archive", and is essentially a collection of hyperlinks

You will need to use the TCIA downloader client ("NBIA Retriever") to get the actual DICOM files you want.

You can download it using the following guide:
https://wiki.cancerimagingarchive.net/display/NBIA/Downloading+TCIA+Images

Once installed, a simple double-click on a .tcia file should open the NBIA retriever client.